# Regular expression to extract filename broken on '++' in filename

Tags: python, regex, filenames, ldd

I'm working on a utility to assist others in resolving dependency hell. I can extract the UNIX path output by ldd but in one case my regex is not able to handle the presence of 2 +'s in the filename. My regular expression is below:

```
((?:\\/[\\w\\.\\-]+)+)
```

Any ideas how I could modify this to handle the +'s?

Test data is:

```
libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf5431000)
```

Thanks in advance if anyone has input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the square brackets, the `.` and `-` lose their special meaning (well - the `-` loses it when it's the last one`. Why not just add the`+` to the allowable characters:

```
((?:\/[\w.+-]+)+)
```

See demo: http://regex101.com/r/vN4bJ2

[image]